# How to live count input if value is entered or active by using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to count the input after it is filled with numbers, but if it is not filled then the input is not counted.

I tried using the following HTML

```
<input type="number" class="myclass" value="4">
<input type="number" class="myclass" value="2">
<input type="number" class="myclass" value="0"> <!-- "0" / blank, not counted -->
<input type="number" class="myclass" value="3">

<!-- count result = 3 -->
<div id="count"></div>
```

and javascript

```
function livecountinput(){
let num = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass').length;
let count = document.getElementById('count');
count.innerHTML = num
};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   livecountinput();
});
```

all that works but if there are zeros still counted, how to solve it?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `myclass` should be `class` and not `type`, correct? In javascript you are not accesing the `value` property of any input. I think you should consider that.

Comment: @Carlos Sorry, I wrote it wrong, all that works but if there are zeros still counted, how to solve it?

Comment: are you sure it is not working? I tried it out and it works for me. https://jsfiddle.net/ghmvzLdc/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `document.getElementsByClassName('myclass').length` you get the length of the array with HTMLNodes. If you have 4 elements with that class name then you get a length of 4. Maybe this is what you want:

```js
function livecountinput() {
  let numNodes = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');
  let length = [...numNodes].filter((node) => parseInt(node.value) !== 0).length
  let count = document.getElementById('count');
    count.innerHTML = length
};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  livecountinput();
});
```

```html
<input type="number" class="myclass" value="4">
<input type="number" class="myclass" value="2">
<input type="number" class="myclass" value="0"> <!-- "0" / blank, not counted -->
<input type="number" class="myclass" value="3">

<!-- count result = 3 -->
<div id="count"></div>
```

Comment: I will add `onkeyup="livecountinput()` because I want to make it live, if the input is changed then all counts will change live.